# Converse.js don't want to connect localhost ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I configured on my debug machine ejabberd with next ejabberd.cfg:

```
override_local.
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "localhost"}}.
{hosts, ["localhost"]}.
{loglevel, 4}.
{listen,
 [
  {5222, ejabberd_c2s, [
            {access, c2s},
            {shaper, c2s_shaper},
            {max_stanza_size, 65536},
                        %%zlib,
            starttls, {certfile, "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"}
               ]},

  {5269, ejabberd_s2s_in, [
               {shaper, s2s_shaper},
               {max_stanza_size, 131072}
              ]},
  {5280, ejabberd_http, [
                         {request_handlers, [
                                             {["xmpp-httpbind"], mod_http_bind}
                          ]},
                          http_bind,
                          http_poll,
                          web_admin
   ]}
]}.
{auth_method, internal}.
{shaper, normal, {maxrate, 1000}}.
{shaper, fast, {maxrate, 50000}}.
{acl, local, {user_regexp, ""}}.
{access, max_user_sessions, [{10, all}]}.
{access, max_user_offline_messages, [{5000, admin}, {100, all}]}. 
{access, local, [{allow, local}]}.
{access, c2s, [{deny, blocked},
           {allow, all}]}.
{access, c2s_shaper, [{none, admin},
              {normal, all}]}.
{access, s2s_shaper, [{fast, all}]}.
{access, announce, [{allow, admin}]}.
{access, configure, [{allow, admin}]}.
{access, muc_admin, [{allow, admin}]}.
{access, muc, [{allow, all}]}.
{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
{access, pubsub_createnode, [{allow, all}]}.
{language, "en"}.
{modules,
 [
  {mod_adhoc,    []},
  {mod_announce, [{access, announce}]}, % requires mod_adhoc
  {mod_caps,     []},
  {mod_configure,[]}, % requires mod_adhoc
  {mod_admin_extra, []},
  {mod_disco,    []},
  {mod_irc,      []},
  {mod_last,     []},
  {mod_muc,      [
          %%{host, "conference.@HOST@"},
          {access, muc},
          {access_create, muc},
          {access_persistent, muc},
          {access_admin, muc_admin},
          {max_users, 500}
         ]},
  {mod_offline,  [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]},
  {mod_privacy,  []},
  {mod_private,  []},
  {mod_proxy65,  [
          {access, local},
          {shaper, c2s_shaper}
         ]},
  {mod_pubsub,   [ % requires mod_caps
          {access_createnode, pubsub_createnode},
          {pep_sendlast_offline, false},
          {last_item_cache, false},
          %%{plugins, ["default", "pep"]}
          {plugins, ["flat", "hometree", "pep"]}  % pep requires mod_caps
         ]},
  {mod_register, [
          {welcome_message, {"Welcome!",
                     "Welcome to a Jabber service powered by Debian. "
                     "For information about Jabber visit "
                     "http://www.jabber.org"}},
          {access, register}
         ]},
  {mod_roster,   []},
  {mod_stats,    []},
  {mod_time,     []},
  {mod_vcard,    []},
  {mod_version,  []}
 ]}.
```

Now I can successfully log in and register via Pidgin client. But when I launch conversejs client as described [here](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/quickstart.html) with bosh_service_url "http://localhost:5280/http-bind/" and try log in with an existing account, converse js hangs on and do nothing. Signing up does not available too. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You defined your handler as "xmpp-httpbind" in config file.

You BOSH URL endpoint should be: "http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind/"

Comment: Still have "internal-server-error" after "fetch registration form" button clicking with "localhost" value on "xmpp provider's domain name" and hanging while logging in with admin@localhost as user

Comment: Which ejabberd version are you using  ? What do you have in ejabberd logs ?